# How does LA24.org achieve the side menu proximity animation?

Tags: javascript, css, html

The LA24.org website has a side menu that responds to the mouse cursor proximity and position relative to the menu. It's as if they were magnets and the mouse was pulling the menu.

How was this achieved? Are there any libraries that provide this behavior?

Comment: Called simple physics... This is not a google for code. Please try it first, if you get stuck ask us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's custom code. A possible way to do it is to use canvas for the edge of the menu to create the organic / magnetic pull effect towards the mouse.

In javascript you can add a listener to the mousemove event. In the canvas element you can draw a beziercurve towards the mouse coordinate at a certain threshold (when the mouse is close enough to the menu). If the mouse is almost touching the menu, the menu expands. In this case I added a class to the menu when the mouse is close enough to it, which animates the left position of the menu so it slides into view.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

function draw(x,y){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x,y,x,y,0,400);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();    
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  $(".container").removeClass('expand');
  if(e.x < 200 && e.x > 100){
    draw(200-e.x + 20, e.y);
  }
  else if(e.x < 100){
    $(".container").addClass('expand');
    draw(0,0);
  }else{
    draw(0,0);
  }
})
```

I made a rough codepen to demonstrate it: http://codepen.io/peerbolte/pen/JRJdVo

Comment: Thanks so much @peerbolte for your helpful and constructive response.